# How does one go about finding an obscure journal and paper?

Tags: publications, citations, journals

I was reading a review paper which cited another paper, however for the life of me I cannot seem to find any hits on the cited paper. The author, title and journal return nothing on the usual sources (Google mainly). What is the best course of action to go about finding such a paper?

The citation is "R. Badulescu et al.,in
Proc. Innov. Sustainability Conf., vol. 40, 2017,
pp. 1–4."

Comment: Academic librarians are really good at this sort of thing. Perhaps you have a way to ask one.

Comment: You should specify what the "usual sources" are (google, other multi-purpose search engines, …?). Try to look up the first author if you can, or *any* edition of those proceedings. If everything else fails, you can also contact the corresponding author of  the paper you were reading and ask them if they could share a pointer / way of getting this paper.

Comment: @Buffy - I continue to be amazed that people don’t remember/learn of research librarians these days. The best friend a PhD student can have for literature reviews, and ever after. Spending a few hours with one is an eye opening experience.

Comment: @Clément Google is my main source. What I find strange is, I cannot even get any meaningful hits on the Journal.

Comment: @Amal What's the title of the paper? I happened to see a librarian today and show her your question. She said knowing the title could help her to find it. I think your librarian probably would ask the same question.

Comment: This is not a shopping question, but it is a "content of research" question.

Comment: "really good" is understating what a good reference librarian is capable of. I've seen librarians track down books containing English translations of century-old papers originally published in Russian.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not a journal, it's a volume of proceedings from a conference (which you can derive from the format "Proc. X Conf.").

It looks like these are proceedings from a conference held in Bucharest, Romania, in 2017. It may have been a local conference; online sources are very limited in English and slightly less limited in Romanian.

As Buffy suggested in the comments, your best bet is to ask your local academic librarian.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a link for the abstract book (p. 41)
http://innovation.pub.ro/archive/2017.pdf

The easiest thing would be to email the authors.

I found the article by searching in Google Scholar (scholar.google.com) for your reference. With more details I searched for some of the author names. I think the accent in the name Bădulescu might confuse the search engines.

Comment: To the OP, please note the last line on p.42 on pdf: _For the purchase of the full paper please contact the authors._. You may have to pay for the paper.

Comment: Thank you so much! What did you put in Google Scholar? I could not get any results by simply copy pasting the reference. Is it the accent that made the difference?

Comment: Another really odd thing is that the conference seems to be totally unrelated to the area of the paper. I think this has made it even harder to search.

Comment: You're welcome. I first put in GS the whole bit in quotes that you put in your question. That got me to the IEEE paper by Wainstein from which you got that reference. That got me the title of Badulescu's paper. I copied that into Google and found it in the list of publications of IMT-Bucharest. After a few trial-and-errors, I searched Google for "Badulescu Mircea Dragoman" (M.D. seems to be the head of the lab or some such, because his name is on most of the papers there.) That got me the pdf I linked to.

Comment: A bit odd that most of the authors are from the university - could be a university conference with a "publication", there may not have been peer-review done.